# SQL combining two row results into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]My DDLs

```
create table Employee
(employeeID varchar(10) not null primary key,
fName varchar(20) not null,
mName varchar(20) not null,
lName varchar(20) not null,
DOB date,
position varchar(15)not null,
addres varchar(40)not null,
warehouseID varchar(10)foreign key references Warehouse(warehouseID),
retailshopID varchar(10)foreign key references Retailshop(retailshopID),
customerID varchar(10)foreign key references Customer(customerID),
);

create table Warehouse_Province
(provinceID varchar(10) not null primary key,
province varchar (25) not null,
city varchar (25) not null,
addresss varchar (40) not null,
);


create table Warehouse
(warehouseID varchar(10) not null primary key,
qtyofStocks int not null,
reorderQty int not null,
provinceID varchar(10)foreign key references     Warehouse_Province(provinceID)
);

create table Retailshop_Provice
(retailprovinceID varchar(10) not null primary key,
province varchar (25) not null,
city varchar (25) not null,
addresss varchar (40) not null,
);

create table Retailshop
(retailshopID varchar(10) not null primary key,
retailprovinceID varchar(10)foreign key references Retailshop_Provice(retailprovinceID));
```

I need to make a query to List all the employees that work in both retail shop and warehouses along with the city where they work.
for this i made an SQL statement

```
SELECT  e.employeeID,e.fName, e.mName, e.lName,whp.city,rsp.city
FROM Employee e,Warehouse w ,Warehouse_Province whp,Retailshop   r,Retailshop_Provice rsp 
WHERE (e.warehouseID=w.warehouseID AND w.provinceID = whp.provinceID)OR(e.retailshopID=r.retailshopID AND r.retailprovinceID = rsp.retailprovinceID);
```

However the result i get has two rows for city,how could i combine them as the below sql result but i want it to show only one row for City without including it in two seperate SQL i want to combine it into one SQL with results showing employee names and the city they work at.

```
SELECT  e.employeeID,e.fName, e.mName, e.lName,whp.city
FROM Employee e,Warehouse w ,Warehouse_Province whp 
WHERE (e.warehouseID=w.warehouseID AND w.provinceID = whp.provinceID)

SELECT e.employeeID, e.fName, e.mName, e.lName,rsp.city
FROM Employee e,Retailshop r,Retailshop_Provice rsp 
WHERE e.retailshopID=r.retailshopID  AND  r.retailprovinceID=rsp.retailprovinceID;
```

sample table should look like this

```
employee  fname lname  whpcity rspcity 

a         mr    x      NULL  city2

b         mr    y      city1   NULL

a         mr    x      NULL  city1

b         mr    y      city2   NULL
```

Comment: where is your customer table?

Comment: i did not include the customer table but it exists, i would like  to know if i can combine the result of two rows as one for City  ,namely,Retail Shop province  and Warehouse province data about the City

Comment: it could be better if you provide some sample data. also whether rhp.city and whp.city both are different? Do you need the city column as comma sperated value?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Not Clear about your Expected Output. I assume the output you got is as below

```
employee  fname lname  whpcity rspcity 

a         mr    x      city1   city2

b         mr    y      city1   city2

a         mr    x      city2   city1

b         mr    y      city2   city1
```

In the above you need to use Stuff along with xmlpath to concatenate the city's belong to each employee

```
SELECT employee, fname, lname, STUFF ((SELECT ','+ whpcity 
                                from #emp e1
                                where e1.employee = e2.employee

                                FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,1,'') as whpcity
from #emp e2
group by employee, fname, lname
```

the output you will get is as below

```
employee    fname       lname       whpcity
a           mr          x           city1,city2
B           mr          Y           city2,city1
```

Also I suggest you to use ANSI-syntax while Joining two tables.

```
SELECT  e.employeeID,e.fName, e.mName, e.lName,whp.city as whpcity,rsp.city as rspcity
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN 
Warehouse w 
ON ( e.warehouseID=w.warehouseID)
INNER JOIN Warehouse_Province whp
on (w.provinceID = whp.provinceID)
inner join Retailshop r
on (e.retailshopID=r.retailshopID)
inner join Retailshop_Provice rsp
on (r.retailprovinceID = rsp.retailprovinceID)
```

Comment: my expected output is whenever there is a retailshop city there should be a warehouse shop city with null

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the output you got?

Comment: sure.Please Check ,il show you the required output to be shown

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Joining the Employee table with Warehouse tables as well as the Retailshop tables should work.

```
SELECT  e.employeeID,e.fName, e.mName, e.lName,
whp.city as warehouse_city,
rsp.city as retail_city
FROM Employee e,
Warehouse w ,
Warehouse_Province whp,
Retailshop r,
Retailshop_Provice rsp
WHERE (e.warehouseID=w.warehouseID AND w.provinceID = whp.provinceID
AND e.retailshopID=r.retailshopID  AND  r.retailprovinceID=rsp.retailprovinceID);
```

Otherwise, Try joining the results of both the queries which you mentioned, based on employee id. An Outer shell join of independent results in initial level.

Its either `A & B & C` or `(A & B) & (A & C)`